# Multiple databases with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following scenario - Our desktop application talks to a SQL Server on another machine. We are using Nhibernate 2.1.2. Now, we want to use SQLite on client machine to store data which could not be uploaded. For example, if Order table has not been updated on SQL Server, we want to save it to SQLite. And, then later try to upload to SQL Server. So, we are thinking to use Nhibernate for storing data in SQLite. How do I configure NHibernate to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a whole new session/session source. NHibernate can not simply switch contexts with the push of a button. Best bet is to spin up a separate repository and session that point at that specific second database.